# C++ thread pool class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

**I have addressed the critique for this post and resubmitted it for iterative review;** *[C++ multithread pool class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203435).*

Class for creating thread pools with the latest C++ standard. Currently C++17 and C++2a.

- It currently only accepts and executes parameterless routines.
- Multiple functions may be enqueued via variadic template or stl
  vector.
- The number of threads created in the pool is relative to the
  hardware concurrency by means of a user multiplier. If the hardware
  concurrency cannot be determined it will default to four and the
  number of threads created will be two, four, or eight depending on
  the multiplier used.

Please review code correctness, best practices, design and implementation.

Please assume the namespace Mercer is to be used as a cross-platform library.

This code **was** also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/sixequalszero/C-), but now contains current iteration.

**mercer.h**

```
//File          mercer.h
//Author        Michael Mercer
//Copyleft      CC BY-SA
//Description   Header for universal declarations used in namespace Mercer

#ifndef MERCER_H_0000
#define MERCER_H_0000
/*#####################-----           Mercer         -----###################*/
/*                             universal declarations                         */
namespace Mercer
{
    enum struct execution: bool {failure, success};
}
/*                                                                            */
/*#####################-----           Mercer         -----###################*/
#endif //MERCER_H_0000
```

**multithread.h**

```
//File          multithread.h
//Author        Michael Mercer
//Copyleft      CC BY-SA
//Description   Header for multithread class

#ifndef MULTITHREAD_H_0000
#define MULTITHREAD_H_0000
/*#####################-----        multithread       -----###################*/
/*                        class for multithread interface                     */

/* GCC Bug 84330 - [6/7 Regression] [concepts] ICE with broken constraint
#ifndef __cpp_concepts
static_assert(false, "Concepts TS NOT found");
#endif

#include <type_traits>

template<typename dataType>
concept bool Function()
{
    return  std::is_function<dataType>::value;
}
*/

#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>

#include "mercer.h"

namespace Mercer
{

//Multithread class
//if !joinable no new routines may be enqueued
class multithread
{
    class implementation;
    std::unique_ptr<implementation> data;

public:

    enum struct concurrency: int  {half, full, twofold};

    multithread(concurrency quantity);
    multithread(); //concurrency::full
    ~multithread();

    execution enqueue(const std::vector<std::function<void()>>&&);
    //consumes std::vector iff execution::success

    execution enqueue(const std::function<void()>&&);

    template<typename ... dataType>
    execution enqueue(const std::function<void()>&& proximate   ,
                      const std::function<void()>&& penproximate,
                      dataType ...                  parameters  )
    {
        if(execution::success==
            enqueue(std::forward<const std::function<void()>>(proximate   )   ))
            enqueue(std::forward<const std::function<void()>>(penproximate)   ,
                    std::forward<dataType                   >(parameters  )...);
        else
            return execution::failure;
        return execution::success;
    }

    execution join();
    execution detach();

    bool thrown() const noexcept;
    std::exception_ptr getNextException() const;
    //If thrown()==true, will never throw
    //If get final exception, thrown() will reset to false
};

}//namespace Mercer
/*                                                                            */
/*#####################-----        multithread       -----###################*/ 
#endif //MULTITHREAD_H_0000
```

**multithread.cpp**

```
//File          multithread.cpp
//Author        Michael Mercer
//Copyleft      CC BY-SA
//Description   Source for multithread class

/*#####################-----        multithread       -----###################*/
/*                        class for multithread interface                     */

#include "multithread.h"
using Mercer::multithread;
using Mercer::execution;
using function = std::function<void()>;

struct multithread::implementation
{
    enum struct close: bool {detach, join};

    std::queue<std::exception_ptr> exceptions;

    bool                     open ;
    std::deque <function>    line ;
    std::mutex               door ;
    std::condition_variable  guard;
    std::vector<std::thread> pool ;

    implementation(concurrency quantity) :
        open(true),
        line(),
        door(),
        guard(),
        pool(std::invoke( [&]
            {
                std::vector<std::thread> temp;
                unsigned threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
                if(threads==0)
                    threads=4;
                switch(quantity)
                {
                    case concurrency::half   : threads /= 2; break;
                    case concurrency::full   :               break;
                    case concurrency::twofold: threads *= 2; break;
                }
                temp.reserve(threads);
                for(auto i=threads; i>0; i--)
                    temp.emplace_back(  [&]
                        {
                            function next;
                            bool perpetual = true;
                            while(perpetual)
                            {
                                std::unique_lock lock(door);
                                guard.wait(lock, [&]
                                    {
                                        return !line.empty() || !open;
                                    } );
                                if(!line.empty())
                                {
                                    next = std::forward<function>(line.front());
                                    line.pop_front();
                                    if(!open && line.empty())
                                        perpetual = false;
                                    lock.unlock();
                                    guard.notify_one();
                                    try
                                    {
                                        next();
                                    }
                                    catch(...)
                                    {
                                        exceptions.emplace(
                                            std::current_exception() );
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(!open)
                                    perpetual = false;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                return temp;
            }) )
        {}

    template<close closeType>
    execution close()
    {
        auto result = execution::success;
        if (open==true)
        {
            open = false;
            guard.notify_all();
            for (auto&& thread : pool)
                if (thread.joinable())
                    switch(closeType)
                    {
                        case close::join  : thread.join()  ; break;
                        case close::detach: thread.detach(); break;
                    }
            pool.clear();   
            pool.shrink_to_fit();
        }
        else
            result = execution::failure;
        return result;
    }
};

multithread::multithread(concurrency quantity):
    data(std::make_unique<implementation>(quantity))
{}

multithread::multithread():
    data(std::make_unique<implementation>(concurrency::full))
{}

execution multithread::join()
{
    return data->close<implementation::close::join>();
}

execution multithread::detach()
{
    return data->close<implementation::close::detach>();
}

multithread::~multithread()
{
    join();
}

execution multithread::enqueue(const function&& item)
{
    auto result = execution::success;
    if (data->open==true)
    {
        std::scoped_lock(data->door);
        data->line.emplace_back(std::forward<const function>(item));
        data->guard.notify_all();
    }
    else
        result = execution::failure;
    return result;
}

execution multithread::enqueue(const std::vector<function>&& adjunct)
{
    auto result = execution::success;
    if (data->open==true)
    {
        std::scoped_lock(data->door);
        data->line.insert(data->line.end(),
                          make_move_iterator(adjunct.begin()) ,
                          make_move_iterator(adjunct.end()  ));
        data->guard.notify_all();
    }
    else
        result = execution::failure;
    return result;
}

bool multithread::thrown() const noexcept
{
    return data->exceptions.empty() ? false : true;
}

std::exception_ptr multithread::getNextException() const
{
    if(thrown())
    {
        auto temp = std::forward<std::exception_ptr>(data->exceptions.front());
        data->exceptions.pop();
        return temp;
    }
    else
        throw std::out_of_range("Thrown() is false, no exception to get");
}
/*                                                                            */
/*#####################-----        multithread       -----###################*/
```

Comment: I hate us-less comments: `//Description  Header for universal declarations used in namespace Mercer`. If you are going to have comments (a code smell for now writing readable code). Then they should be meaningful. Maintaining comments is just as important as maintaining the code. Garbage/Useless comments are not maintained and they will fall out of sync with the code. When code and comments are out of sync hell is unleashed. Is the code correct and comments wrong or vice versa. How can I tell. The answer: **Only write comments that provide real information.**

Comment: Mediocre comment: `GCC Bug 84330 - [6/7 Regression] [concepts]`. Would have been nice with a link so we can go look at the bug report.

Comment: Don't abuse lambda's like that. Make the lambda call a member keep it short. Also that way you can write self documenting code and call other `NAMED` functions.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175025/12917

Comment: Note: I also think File/Author are superfluous comments and just add noise. These are things you get from your source control system not from comments. Rather than add copyright in each file add a copyright file to the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `multithread::enqueue` parameter type issues

> This section is trying to address all overloads of this member function, as these issues affect all of them.

Why take parameters of the form `const X&&` (where `X` is either `std::function<void()>` or `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`)?

Going from this comment `//consumes std::vector iff execution::success`, my best guess is that those was intended to just be plain rvalue references (without the `const`), since you simply cannot "consume" (i.e. modify) a `const X`.

> This also means going through all the trouble of using a `move_iterator` on the `const std::vector<std::function<void()>>&&` overload would be for nought, as it would have to make a copy.

So, let's just drop the `const`.

---

Now, there still seems to be some confusion about `std::forward`. `std::forward` is intended to be used on so called forwarding references (reference of type `T&&`, where `T` is deduced locally), where it passes them on as the function received them (i.e. it moves rvalue references, but not lvalue references).

Since we know that the parameters in calls to `std::forward` are actual rvalue references (*), we can simply call `std::move` instead.

> (*) Well, there's the exception in the template overload: `dataType... parameters`.
>
> First off, `dataType` will never be deduced to be any kind of reference; instead, copies will be created and passed on. `std::forward` masked these copies by calling `std::move` on them (since it didn't get instantiated with a reference type). This would make the actual relevant parameters (`proximate` and possibly `penproximate`) rvalue references, as required, and move-construct the new `parameters`.
>
> This can be fixed by changing `dataType... parameters` to `dataType&&... parameters`. Now, since `parameters` are forward references, we actually want to call `std::forward<dataType>(parameters)...`. Now they get passed through by `std::forward` without any copies being made.
>
> Additionally, calling `enqueue` with anything but a `std::function<void>&&` now causes a compile time error, as the compiler cannot match a lvalue reference to a rvalue reference parameter. (This could optionally be explicitly asserted up front with some template metaprogramming in order to give a cleaner error message.)

## Concurrency issues

While unlikely to ever happen on a x86 CPU, technically accesses to `implementation::open` are possible data races (there's no synchronization around reads or writes).

Also, since the value of `open` ostensibly doesn't get changed inside the lambda passed to the threads, the optimizer could cache that value in a register (unlikely, but allowed), so changes to `implementation::open` might not be visible to the worker threads at all!

A simple solution to both of these issues would be chaging `implementation::open` to `std::atomic<bool>`.

## General stuff

- A lot of functions have the following pattern:

  ```
  XXX return_value = default_value;

  if(condition) { /* do_stuff */ }
  else { return_value = other_value; }

  return return_value;
  ```

  This can be simplified to:

  ```
  if(!condition) return other_value;

  /* do_stuff */

  return default_value;
  ```
- The function called to initialize `implementation::pool` and the worker thread functions could be refactored into their own functions. This would increase readability by quite a lot.

Comment: Currently pressed for time, might add more later.

Comment: Thanks @hoffmale, I have addressed your critique and resubmitted for [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204387/). I would greatly appreciate your input once again.